Generate array of positive integers that sum of to k
My task is simple: I want to generate an (ideally numpy) array containing all combinations of m positive (>=0), but bounded (<= e) integers that sum exactly to k. Note that k and m might be relatively high, so generating all combinations and filtering will not work.
I have implemented it in plain, recursive python but this small functions takes most of my time and I need to replace it to perform better. I have tried to come up with numpy/pytorch code to generate this array but I didn't manage to do it so far.
I currently use numpy and pytorch in my project, but I am open to other libraries as long as I write python code and I get something I can convert to numpy arrays in the end.
Here's some code:
import timeit


def get_summing_up_to(max_degree, sum, length, current=0):
    assert sum >= 0
    assert length >= 1
    if length == 1:
        residual = sum - current
        if residual <= max_degree:
            return [(residual,)]
        else:
            return []
    max_element = min(max_degree, sum - current)
    return [
        (i,) + t
        for i in range(max_element + 1)
        for t in get_summing_up_to(
            max_degree, sum, length - 1,
            current=current + i
        )
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = timeit.timeit('get_summing_up_to(60, 60, 6)', globals=globals(), number=1)
    print(f"Execution time: {result} for max_degree=60, sum=60, length=6")

    result = timeit.timeit('get_summing_up_to(30, 30, 8)', globals=globals(), number=1)
    print(f"Execution time: {result} for max_degree=30, sum=30, length=8")


Can you include your best attempt and give some metric (like time it runs for a certain m and k) that is unacceptable, and what it should be instead?

will do, simplifying it right now

Is order important? E.g, if you wanted all pairs of integers summing to 2, would the answer be [(0, 2), (1, 1)] or [(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)]?

ideally, I want all combinations. In theory, I can also deal with non-decreasing order (or the other way as long as I know what I get)

This feels like a classic DP problem. Might be able to implement some storage of past computations to dramatically improve computation time.

Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7748851/235698

yes, but I don't see how that's faster.

How big are N and K for your problem?

a good test is N=6 and K=130

maybe a lower combination is faster to develop though :)

@Leander Faster than what?  You've shown no code or benchmarks.

added some simple benchmark

@Leander OK, in my measurement the link I posted is 12% faster for your benchmarks.  Use list(sums(6,60)) and list(sums(8,30)).

« a_good_test_is_N=6_and_K=130 » What is N? So far, you've mentioned, K, M and E (in any case), and, in your code, max_degree, sum (avoid naming variable sum, btw. It is a native python function) and length, and it is not hard to understand that max_degree is E, length it M and sum is K. But what is N?

Note that, on my computer (but I've to try on another one) the main problem is not really the time displayed by timeit, but the real ellapsed time (even without any competition for the CPU). Timeit shows, roughly, 30 seconds and 1 min for the two examples of your main. But using unix time to compute time consumed by python process shows around 30 secs user time, 1 min sys time (1'+30'' are the 1'30'' given by timeit in total. Obviously the fact that both addition  are 1'+30'' is a coincidence. It is not "user time" for the 1st computation, and "sys time" for the second).

But total real time is 6 min 30 seconds. So 5 minutes of real time. And the reason why I've measured this was because I had the feeling that it lasted longer than timeit result (which shouldn't be sensible with your number=1). And also because my cpu load meter was flat for long period of times. So, process takes time, but CPU is not even used!

So, my guess is that, as you pointed out, it has something to do with the zillions allocations of tuples you are doing. So, maybe, one way would be to try to preallocate the data.

Just one simple thing, in the meantime: just adding if max_degree*length+current<S: return [] gave a 10% gain here. To cut early the branches that have no chance to reach S (S is my name for sum)

One thing to notice is your function generates redundant outputs. ie get_summing_up_to(30, 30, 8) would contain (30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ....
One way to make this more efficient is to generate unique integer combinations excluding 0s from 1 to max_length. We can also add caching to the sub-problem of generating partitions for added efficiency.
from functools import lru_cache

def get_summing_up_to_minimal(max_value, target_sum, max_length):
    # optional caching - setting maxsize recommended 
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def generate_partitions(remaining_sum, max_val, length):
        # Early pruning conditions
        if remaining_sum < 0:
            return []
        if length == 0:
            return [()] if remaining_sum == 0 else []
        
        # Minimum possible sum with given length (using all 1's)
        if remaining_sum < length:
            return []
        
        # Maximum possible sum with given length (using max_val)
        if remaining_sum > max_val * length:
            return []
            
        # Base case for length 1
        if length == 1:
            return [(remaining_sum,)] if remaining_sum <= max_val else []

        results = []
        # Optimize the start value
        start = min(max_val, remaining_sum)
        # Calculate minimum value needed to achieve remaining_sum with remaining length
        min_required = (remaining_sum - 1) // length + 1
        
        # Iterate only through viable values
        for i in range(start, min_required - 1, -1):
            # Early pruning: check if remaining values can sum to target
            remaining_length = length - 1
            remaining_target = remaining_sum - i
            
            # If maximum possible sum with remaining length is too small, break
            if i * remaining_length < remaining_target:
                break
                
            # If minimum possible sum with remaining length is too large, continue
            if remaining_target < remaining_length:
                continue
                
            sub_partitions = generate_partitions(
                remaining_target,
                min(i, max_val),
                remaining_length
            )
            
            for sub_partition in sub_partitions:
                results.append((i,) + sub_partition)
        
        return results

    all_partitions = []
    # Only try lengths that could possibly work
    min_length = (target_sum - 1) // max_value + 1
    max_possible_length = min(max_length, target_sum)
    
    for length in range(min_length, max_possible_length + 1):
        partitions = generate_partitions(target_sum, max_value, length)
        all_partitions.extend(partitions)
    
    return all_partitions

If the full output with redundant results is required, we can generate them after the fact using the minimal set of outputs from get_summing_up_to_minimal:
from itertools import permutations

def expand_partitions(compact_partitions, max_length):
    result = []
    
    for partition in compact_partitions:
        # Calculate how many zeros we need to add
        zeros_needed = max_length - len(partition)
        if zeros_needed < 0:
            continue
            
        # Create the full partition with zeros
        full_partition = partition + (0,) * zeros_needed
        
        # Generate all unique permutations
        # Using a set to handle cases where partition contains duplicate numbers
        result.extend(set(permutations(full_partition)))
    
    return result

Note that expanding partitions would be the bulk of compute time.
I profiled the following:
# run 1, your original code
out = get_summing_up_to(30, 60, 6)

# run 2, generating just minimal outputs
out = get_summing_up_to_minimal(30, 60, 6)

# run 3, generate minimal outputs and expand to full outputs
out = get_summing_up_to_minimal(30, 60, 6)
out = expand_partitions(out, 8)

On my machine, your original code takes ~4.6 seconds. Generating the minimal outputs takes ~17.9 milliseconds. Generating the minimal outputs and expanding takes ~1.1 seconds.
If your downstream use case doesn't require the redundant combinations, you can save a lot of time just generating the minimal set. If you need to pack the outputs into a numpy array/torch tensor (requiring everything be the same length), you can pad the minimal outputs to max_length with zeros without generating all the combinations. ie:
out = get_summing_up_to_minimal(30, 60, 6)
out_array = np.zeros((len(out), 6))

for i, o in enumerate(out):
    out_array[i][:len(o)] = sorted(o)


If you want to find all combinations you can use itertools. If you want replacement after each selection use combinations_with_replacement and in that case combinations such as (m,m) will be allowed. Otherwise use combination.
import numpy as np
import itertools

e = 10 # the limit
# generate elements to be combined
# so they are from 0 to e
# with 1 spacing in between each
elements = np.linspace(0,e,e+1,dtype=int)
# But this can be `Astring`, (tu,ple), ['List', 'of', 'anything'], ...

r = 2 # combinations of r elements
# Generate all combinations of r elements
comb = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(elements, r)

# print all the combinations as tuples
print(list(comb))

The print shows
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 10), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 10), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 10), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 10), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 10), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 10), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 10), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 10), (8, 8), (8, 10), (10, 10)]

Then you filter the list to keep only combinations that sums up to k like this
k_combs = []

k = 2 # only keeps tuple that sums up to 2
for i,j in enumerate(list(comb)):
    if np.sum(j) == k:
        k_combs.append(j)

print(k_combs)

Which gives
[(0, 2), (1, 1)]

I don't want every naive combinations but only the ones that sum up to k

Then you can just sums all elements in tuple with np.sum() and filter with a simple if. Check the edit ...

yeah, but that's slower than my solution, right? I want something faster

Can you be more specific on the values you have and the wall clock execution time ?

I have added some code with the function to beat

We can frame this as a balls and boxes problem. Slowest step is conversion of generator to numpy array.
def get_summing_up_to2(max_degree, sum, length):
    p = np.array(list(combinations(range(0, sum + length -1), length-1)))

    p[:, 1:] = p[:, 1:] - p[:, 0:-1] - 1
    p[:, 0] = p[:, 0] - 0
    p = np.append(p, (sum - np.sum(p, axis = 1))[:, None], axis = 1)

    p = p[np.max(p, axis = 1) <= max_degree]

    p = p[np.all(np.diff(p) >= 0, axis = 1)]

    return p

Metrics on my machine:
Original:
Execution time: 6.023083299980499 for max_degree=60, sum=60, length=6
Execution time: 10.017814500024542 for max_degree=30, sum=30, length=8

V2:
Execution time: 3.8685075999237597 for max_degree=60, sum=60, length=6
Execution time: 5.6449807999888435 for max_degree=30, sum=30, length=8


To solve this problem more efficiently, you can leverage itertools.combinations_with_replacement to generate combinations without needing recursion. This approach should improve performance by reducing function call overhead and allowing for more efficient filtering.
import numpy as np
import itertools

def generate_combinations(max_degree, target_sum, length):
    result = []
    for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, max_degree + 1), length):
        if sum(comb) == target_sum:
            result.append(comb)
    return np.array(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = generate_combinations(60, 60, 6)
    print(f"Generated {len(result)} combinations for max_degree=60, sum=60, length=6")
    
    result = generate_combinations(30, 30, 8)
    print(f"Generated {len(result)} combinations for max_degree=30, sum=30, length=8")

